# Why is insert function always appending at end of linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have written this code to insert into a linked list by position.

```
void insert(node *list, int data, int position) {
    int c;

    node *temp; 
    node *prev; 
    node *curr;

    curr = list;

    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->num = data;

    if (curr == NULL) { 
        curr = temp;
        curr->next = NULL;
    } else { 
        while (curr != NULL && c != position) { 
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            c++;
        }
        if (c = 0) { 
            temp->next = curr;
            curr = temp;
        } else if (curr == NULL) { 
            prev->next = temp;
        } else { 
            prev->next = temp;
            temp->next = curr;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I believe this block always executes no matter what and the data gets appended to the end of the linked list.

```
else if (curr == NULL) { 
      prev->next = temp;
```

Why is `curr` always null? It should not get to null if the position is less than the amount of elements in the list...

Comment: First of all: `int c = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized c variable to 0 at the beginning. Also the condition
**if(c = 0)** should have been **if(c == 0)**

temp->next = NULL should also be done after temp->num = data else it will remain uninitialized in case of

```
      else if (curr==NULL) { 
               prev->next=temp;
      }
```

These are few that I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- local variable `c` is not initialized. Using it without prior initialization invokes undefined behavior. You should define it this way:

  ```
  int c = 0;
  ```
- the test `if (c = 0)` sets the value of `c` to `0` and always fails.  Use the `==` operator instead:

  ```
  if (c == 0) {
      ...
  ```
- You must return `list` and set `list` to `curr` is the element was inserted at the start of the list (position 0) or if the list was empty.

Here is an improved version:

```
node *insert(node *list, int data, int position) {
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    temp->num = data;
    if (list == NULL || position <= 0) {
        temp->next = list;
        return temp;
    } else {
        node *curr = list;
        while (position-- > 0 && curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        temp->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = curr;
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void insert` ---> `node *insert`    ;)

Comment: How can you return a node* or NULL from a void function?

Comment: @user3283146: answer corrected. It needed to be *improved* further ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a local variable there: `c`.

That variable has automatic storage and its start value is indeterminate.
**You have to init it**.

```
int c = 0;
```

Otherwise its initial value can be whatever a register old value or memory garbage at the moment the function is called, so

```
while (curr!=NULL && c != position)
```

behavior is undefined.

---

Moreover the if check after the while is bugged: relational operator for equality is `==`

```
if (c=0)
```

must be

```
if (c==0)
```

Otherwise you are assigning `0` to `c` instead of test its value.